# sbt run argument not being read when running tests

Tags: java, scala, testing, build, sbt

I have a java project for which I have used sbt to build. When running tests I'm trying to pass an argument that is not evaluating.

```
sbt "testOnly *LoginTest-DsystemName=AWS1"
```

Am I missing something here? I've already set `fork := true` in build.sbt

Comment: That's not the way of specifying `javaOptions` for a forked `Test` scope. Please first read the documentation

Comment: As @cchantep already mentioned look in the docs, here: http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html

Comment: Thanks that helped. 

sbt '; set javaOptions += "-DsystemName=AWS1" ; testOnly *MatchingTest'